# Find $-3\vec u+4\vec v$ given $u=4\vec i + \vec j$ and $v=5 \vec i - 2\vec j$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, trigonometric-series

Find the vector $-3\vec u+4\vec v$ given vectors $$\vec u=4 \vec \imath + \vec \jmath$$ and $$v=5\vec \imath - \vec \jmath.$$

Write answer in the form $a \vec \imath + b \vec \jmath$.

Comment: It's really simple. $$-3u+4v=-3(4i+j)+4(5i-2j)=-12i-3j+20i-8j=8i-11j$$

Comment: Why on Earth did anyone upvote this?

Comment: Two people have voted to close this as unclear what you're asking. But it's a completely clear question.

Comment: @user236182 I voted to close as offtopic because it is. Although one *could* argue that there is no question here, thus it is "unclear what you're asking". By question I mean starting with a word like who, what or when and ending in a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have ${\bf u} = 4{\bf i} + {\bf j}$ and ${\bf v} = 5{\bf i} - 2{\bf j}$. Then $$\begin{align}-3{\bf u} + 4{\bf v} &= -3(4{\bf i} + {\bf j}) + 4(5{\bf i} - 2{\bf j}) \\ &= -12{\bf i} - 3{\bf j} + 20{\bf i}-8{\bf j} \\ &=8{\bf i} - 11{\bf j} \;\;\;\;\square\end{align}$$

Comment: Why would you answer *that*, have some self respect. :)